# Insect Identification please

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Location Kothrud, Pune
This was found on Sonchafa plant.

[image: Saprophytic insect on leaf.]

Comment: About a centimetre wide in the middle?

Answer (score 3):

It could be a Yellow-spotted stink bug *Erthesina fullo*

https://www.padil.gov.au/pests-and-diseases/pest/main/136074/772

[image]

**EDIT:**

more frequently found in India is *Erthesina acuminata*

http://insecta.pro/taxonomy/1037721

For more information, read the excellent answer on this question:

[Can anyone identify this grey spotted insect -- is it a tree bug species?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76413/can-anyone-identify-this-grey-spotted-insect-is-it-a-tree-bug-species?rq=1)